# When is "marked" pronounced with 2 syllables?

Tags: adjectives, pronunciation, suffixes, syllables

I have heard "marked" [pronounced with 2 syllables like "mar-ked"](https://forvo.com/word/marked_%28distinctive%29/#en) but online dictionaries show only the 1-syllable pronunciation.

When should it be pronounced with 2, and is it a mistake to use swap their use?

What about the word "aged"?

Comment: How about *crooked*? "I saw a crooked man, who walked a crooked mile." ... And there is also *winged* and *legged*.  "The four-legged residents in our house."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Marked* only has two syllables in poetic or archaic usage.

*Aged* has two syllables when used as a noun *(some of the aged need motorised shopping trolleys)*, or as a "standalone" adjective *(an aged relative)*. It's only one syllable when used as part of a compound adjective *(middle-aged relative)*, or as a verb *(I've aged a year since then)*.

Some words occur in "set phrases" where the extra syllable is effectively part of an archaic contruction *(blessed are the meek)*.

EDIT: Per [John Lawler's answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/52253/11762), and comments to mine and his, the word "aged" seems particularly weird. Some people use the one-syllable version for all contexts, but for those who *do* use the two-syllable version, the precise boundaries as to where this is appropriate seem somewhat hard to pin down.

Speaking for myself, I read [this](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=4Cal9x2TlRoC&pg=PA12&dq=%22an%20aged%20map%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=SJTvTtnEDoywhAfsuojNCA&ved=0CDgQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22an%20aged%20map%22&f=false) usage of *an aged map* as being the one-syllable version, but if my "mental lips" were moving while I read, I would say [this one](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=UKwv8WBx9oUC&pg=PA505&dq=%22an%20aged%20map%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=SJTvTtnEDoywhAfsuojNCA&ved=0CEMQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=%22an%20aged%20map%22&f=false) as *"an agéd map"*. I can't easily articulate the distinction, but the *agéd* version seems more appropriate to people, or where the attribution of antiquity implies [venerable](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/venerable) rather than *old and tatty, ravaged by time*.

In the case of *aged cheese, wine, etc*, they're not normally that old anyway - the word just means they've been *matured* for the appropriate length of time, not that they are ancient.

Comment: And as an adjective: 'agèd relative'.

Comment: @Barrie England: noted, ty

Comment: @Daniel: Why, thank you! If I die from over-enthusiastic consumption of alcohol next week, at least I'll have achieved one of my ambitions in life!

Comment: *Aged* doesn't, in my experience, change its pronunciation in US English.

Comment: @onomatomaniak: Weird. So in your experience, *an aged parent* and a *middle-aged parent* both have the word *aged* pronounced the same? Is that with one, or two syllables?

Comment: Yes, in my experience those are both pronounced the same, with single syllables. That said, the dictionary (not surprisingly) disagrees with me. And *that* said, maybe the real issue is that I very rarely hear *aged* as a stand-alone adjective to describe a person. Americans tend to say old or elderly. *Aged cheese*, though, is just like middle-aged: eyjd.

Comment: @onomatomaniak: Well even in British English, *aged parent* is a rather "dated/whimsical" turn of phrase. An "edge case" for me is *"an aged map"*, where I read it as one syllable in *"To create the appearance of an aged map, do this"*. But in *"He took out an aged map"* I read it as two syllables. This one really is an odd word so far as **my** usage is concerned!

Comment: I speak AmE, and I have often said *aged* with two syllables.

Answer (score 6):

I believe, contrary to the above, that the two-syllable pronunciation is quite common in descriptive science in general and, in particular, medical enunciations of symptoms or side-effects of a condition or medication. E.g., "topical application of X is known to cause 'mar-ked' erythema immediately surrounding the area of application".

Comment: Jax Frost is correct. The two-syllable "marked" pronunciation is correctly used in medical terminology and frequently in children's disability hearings. Is is by no means obsolete.

Answer (score 5):

I suspect your confusion stems from the fact that *markedly* is always pronounced as a three syllable word. There's no euphonious way to say it with two syllables, so it hasn't undergone the syllabic reduction common for many *-ed* words in Modern English.

*Marked* alone is one syllable except in archaic/poetic usage, just as FumbleFingers has already ably demonstrated.

Answer (score 3):

*Aged* with one syllable seems to be limited to phrases with a number of years

- *A man aged 46 was arrested yesterday.*

and when referring to non-human things (*aged cheese, well-aged beef, unaged wine*).

Generally speaking, adjectives formed from regular participles, like *wanted, believed, added, whispered,* etc, follow the pronunciation rules for the **{-ED}** past tense morpheme.
{-ED} is pronounced

- /-əd/ after dental stops /t/ and /d/ (because it's impossible to say final /-td/ or /-dd/)
- /-t/ after other voiceless sounds /p k f θ s ʃ/
- /-d/ elsewhere, including after vowels

In the case of *aged*, the final sound is voiced, and therefore /-d/ is possible, but it's an affricate /dʒ/ formed from a dental stop, so the epenthetic shwa is possible, and occurs in some circumstances, as FF notes in his answer.

In the case of *clothed* (*clothed all in white*), either /-d/ or /-əd/ is possible because /ð/ is voiced but also dental (final /-ðd/ is hard to pronounce), though the two syllable version is usually marked with an accent to distinguish it (*clothéd all in white*). See Pratchett & Gaiman's *Good Omens* for some examples.

In the case of *marked*, I think Jonathan has it right -- *markedly* gets the epenthetic shwa to separate the /-ktl-/ cluster, with the /t/ voiced to /d/ by the preceding vowel.

Comment: I'd never thought about [an aged cheese](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=an+aged+cheese&year_start=1700&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) before. It obviously does exist, as that link shows, but it does seem rather unusual to me (and surprisingly recent in terms of popularity). But I'm not sure the two-syllable version only applies with people. You could, for example, just about drive an aged motorcar - surely that would be two syllables?

Comment: ...I think the distinction may be more one of *people, or objects (possibly "personified")* as opposed to *substances, mass-nouns*.

Comment: When I read "an aged cheese", I have this version of a wedge of Wensleydale, tottering down the path pushing a walker. But of course that's only epenthesis having its joke.

Comment: Assuming the "epenthetic" version is the one with the extra syllable, I might think of the *agéd cheese* as being [an old crumbly](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22an+old+crumbly+who%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1). A particularly prized quality of [Cheshire](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22crumbly+cheshire%22&oq=%22crumbly+cheshire%22&aqs=chrome.0.57.14979411&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) and [Lancashire](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22crumbly+lancashire%22&oq=%22crumbly+lancashire%22&aqs=chrome.0.57.15066005&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) cheese (and denizens! :).

Comment: "Epenthesis" means adding an "epenthetic" vowel to produce an extra syllable, usually to separate a complex cluster, the way some people occasionally pronounce _film_ as ['fɪləm]. The trade mnemonic for _epenthesis_ is _epenethesis_, with stress on the third syllable. Just like the mnemonic for _metathesis_ is _methatesis_.

Answer (score 2):

The online [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/marked) dictionary gives the two-syllable pronunciation in audio. This pronunciation goes with the second definition:

> 2 \or ˈmär-kəd\ : having a distinctive or emphasized character ⟨has a marked drawl⟩

(for some reason, this pronunciation doesn't show up on my screen, even though I was able to paste it into this window.)

I definitely remember this pronunciation being used for things like "a markèd limp" when I was younger (maybe 40-50 years ago), but it was rare even then and I would say that this pronunciation is almost obsolete now, even for this meaning, and that there is no reason for you to use it.

Answer (score 0):

As for aged, I think the difference is that the one-syllable (aged cheese) has had a process worked on it, and the two syllable (aged parent) has simply gotten older.  In the case of the map, if I heard it with one syllable I would think someone had intentionally made it look older, and if I heard with two syllables I would think it was just an old map.