# Odd pronunciation of adjectives ending in -ed

Tags: pronunciation

I am currently listening to an audiobook reading of Keats poetry by Sir Ralph Richardson, and I have noticed a peculiar pronunciation of adjectives ending in *-ed*. While I have heard in the past certain words like *winged* being pronounced as *wingid* rather than *wingd*, I thought it an archaic peculiarity of a small subset of words. Yet today I have heard Sir Richardson pronounce *stained* in the same odd fashion, as *steinid* rather than the overwhelmingly more common *steind*. It has made me think and wonder whether this oddity is some sort of literary remnant from the past, or perhaps just a mistake from his part.

For copyright purposes I cannot link to the recording, but if I haven't made myself clear, you can hear what I'm talking about in this publicly available reading of Annabel Lee by Poe.

["Annabel Lee" - Edgar Allan Poe (Poem Version) on Youtube](https://youtu.be/7Q-q02CKo9c?t=53s) (0:54)

Comment: Related: [Are -èd adjectives still usèd words?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/344455/are-èd-adjectives-still-usèd-words), [Are there any pairs of words like “beloved”/“belovèd”, “learned”/“learnèd” that maintain a semantic difference to the present day?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/20997), [Pronunciation of “Blessed”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/6976)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In Shakespeare's time, many words ending *-ed* were pronounced the modern way, with just /t/ or /d/, but many words we pronounce today with /t/ and /d/ were pronounced with /-ɪd/, and for many words, both pronunciations were acceptable.

Shakespeare took advantage of this to make his poetry scan, and often indicated the pronunciation (for those which could be pronounced either way) by spelling them either *mask'd* or *masked*.

By Keats' time, the pronunciation was much closer to the modern version (I don't know whether it was exactly the same), but poets still took advantage of the archaic pronunciations to make their poetry scan, indicating the pronunciation in the same way that Shakespeare did. Keats did this extensively, while Wordsworth seems to have used this quite rarely, if at all.

Comment: In ***blessed** are the meek* it's two syllables for me, but in *the meek are **blessed** by God* it's only one syllable. Much the same with *the **learned** professor **learned** something today*, except I still tend to write ***learnt*** for the second one.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Right. And these pronunciations today are always for adjectives, and not verbs. But I think these pronunciations are disappearing among young people; I think *markèd* is probably already gone (although I remember hearing it when I was younger), and *agèd, blessèd,* and *learnèd* are on their way out.

Comment: Well, I did say I ***still*** tend to write (and enunciate) ***learnt***, so I'd certainly agree that one is heading for the dustbin of history. But I'd have thought everyone still distinguishes *Help the **aged*** from *a well **aged** wine*.

Comment: @PeterShor Perhaps what you heard when younger was "markèdly"? AFAIK "marked" has long been pronounced with silent e. But "markedly" is one of several adverbs in -edly where the e is pronounced (e.g. supposedly, allegedly).

Comment: @Rosie F: [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/marked) still gives a variant two-syllable pronunciation of *marked* for the meaning "having a distinctive or emphasized character; has a *marked* drawl". I suspect this pronunciation is essentially obsolete now, but maybe it was still around 40 years ago. This may be what I remember (although maybe you're right about "markèdly"); *"a markèd man"* sounds utterly wrong to me, but *"a markèd limp"* doesn't.

Comment: @RosieF: There is another question specifically about the adjective"marked" that has some answers that might be of interest: [When is “marked” pronounced with 2 syllables?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/52242)